# Function fails to delete markers from a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The function below does not remove the markers when called. Why?

```
// Remove existing markers from the Map
function removeMarkers(markersArray) {
    var j,position;

    for (j = 0; j < markersArray.length; j += 1){
        position = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: markersArray[j][1], lng: markersArray[j][2]}
        });

        position.setMap(null);
    };
};
```

Here is the array that is being fed into the function:

```
var educationMarkers = [
    ['Grafton Campus, Auckland University', -36.861717, 174.769424],
    ["Auckland Boys' Grammar", -36.872432, 174.768126],
    ["Epsom Girls' Grammar", -36.876177, 174.773639],
    ["St. Peter's College", -36.868412, 174.768575],
    ["ACG Parnell College", -36.863163, 174.778555],
    ["Newmarket Campus, Auckland University", -36.865905, 174.7733]
];
```

Comment: Could you show how you place the marker?

Comment: You have to remove the existing markers.  Your code is creating new markers, then not adding them to the map...

Comment: Below is the function that I use to create markers. Once the markers are on the map, I want to be able to delete them all.

`// Place New Markers on the Map //
function placeMarkers(markersArray) {
 var marker, i, postiion, bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 for (i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i += 1) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   position: {lat: markersArray[i][1], lng: markersArray[i][2]}
  });
  position = new google.maps.LatLng(markersArray[i][1], markersArray[i][2]);
  bounds.extend(position);
 }

map.fitBounds(bounds);

};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep reference of the markers you placed.

```
var placedMarkers = [];

function placeMarkers(markersArray) {
    var marker, i, postiion, bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i += 1) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: {
                lat: markersArray[i][1],
                lng: markersArray[i][2]
            }
        });

        // keep reference of the markers you placed
        placedMarkers.push(marker);

        position = new google.maps.LatLng(markersArray[i][1], markersArray[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
```

and when removing the markers, use the reference array you kept.

```
// Remove existing markers from the Map
function removeMarkers() {
    var j,position;

    // loop through reference array you kept.
    for (j = 0; j < placedMarkers.length; j += 1){
        placedMarkers[j].setMap(null);
    };
};
```

Comment: I also had to add the following line of code into the removeMarkers () function after the for loop:

`placedMarkers = [];`

Answer (score -1):

If the markers in the loop are correct,Just change your for loop with this,Make a fiddler if possible

```
  for (j = 0; j < markersArray.length; j += 1){
    position[j] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: markersArray[j][1], lng: markersArray[j][2]}
    });

    position[j].setMap(null);
  };
```

Comment: `markersArray` is an array of string array. hence, `setMap` is not a function

Comment: Thanks @Neverever edited the code,not sure the marker creation by OP is correct